# Many-to many query

Tags: sql, sqlite

given a relation like this:

```
|Posts |   |Taggins |     |Tags| 
|------|   ----------     ------
| id   |   |  id    |     | id |
           | post_id|     
           | tag_id |
```

I want to find 5 tags with the biggest amount of posts.

I am quite confused how I should approach it with joins and count, as I can't get anything right so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 5 tag_id, count(*) cnt
FROM Taggins
GROUP BY tag_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```